# Masking - Address with Stars (asteriks) - If length of Array is 1?

Tags: java, regex

I have an array out of bounds for this case.

1. If I do:

   String address = "100 Point St Apt B"

   It should be masked too: `100 Po*** St Apt *`
2. If I do:

   String address = "100 Point St Apt 132"

   It is masked too: `100 Po*** St Apt ***`

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong here? Thank you!!

```
public String mask(String address) {
        String[] splitAddress = address.split(" ");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String maskedAddress = "";

    String streetNum = splitAddress[0];
    stringBuilder.append(streetNum + " ");



    for (int i = 1; i < splitAddress.length; i++) {
                String splitFirstTwoCharacters = splitAddress[i].substring(0, 2);
                String remainingCharactersOfAddress = splitAddress[i].substring(2);
                String maskAddress = remainingCharactersOfAddress.replaceAll(".", "*");
                maskedAddress = stringBuilder.append(splitFirstTwoCharacters).append(maskAddress + " ").toString().trim();
    }
 return maskedAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `splitAddress[i].substring(0, 2)` one of the `splitAddress` parts is `B` which does not have an `endIndex` of `2`. Therefore it is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is you are running substring without checking the length of the string.

Here is the fix without too many changes to your existing code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < splitAddress.length; i++) {
    if (splitAddress[i].length() <= 2) {
        stringBuilder.append(splitAddress[i] + " ");
        continue;
    }
    String splitFirstTwoCharacters = splitAddress[i].substring(0, 2);
    String remainingCharactersOfAddress = splitAddress[i].substring(2);
    String maskAddress = remainingCharactersOfAddress.replaceAll(".", "*");
    maskedAddress = stringBuilder.append(splitFirstTwoCharacters).append(maskAddress + " ").toString().trim();
}
return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
```